# Backbone JS Turbolinks Not defined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, turbolinks

I have a backbone JS and Turbolinks app where my code looks like:

```
$(function() {

   var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
       '': 'music',
       'song/:musicID': 'songList'
     },
     ...FUNCTIONS GO HERE
   });

   var appRouter = new AppRouter();
   Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });

});

$(document).on('page:load', function (){
   Backbone.history.stop();
   var appRouter = new AppRouter();
});
```

Basically, at first there are no errors. But after the first page change, I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AppRouter is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem with scope, this should work:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'music',
    'song/:musicID': 'songList'
  },
  ...FUNCTIONS GO HERE
});

$(function() {

   var appRouter = new AppRouter();
   Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });

});

$(document).on('page:load', function (){
   Backbone.history.stop();
   var appRouter = new AppRouter();
});
```

You had declared AppRouter within the scope of the DOM-ready callback and were then trying to reference it within the 'page:load' callback where it wasn't defined. In the code above it's defined in the global scope thus both have access to it.